# Permanent receiving of sent XML over TCP

Tags: c#, xml, websocket

C# Form .Net 4.7

A client app should receive XML data from an external payment machine. The XML is automatically sent after each deposit. It's about receiving it at any time and displaying it in a TextBox.

Sending takes place via TCP

1. The machine opens the connection to the external system at the specified port
2. Sends the data
3. Waits for confirmation on the same connection if necessary
4. Closes the connection

Since the client has to be able to receive the data at any time, I thought about a listener. But I'm not sure if this approach is the right one. What I did here doesn't work. I wanted to test that with a localhost. There is sure to be a simple solution. But since I'm not a network specialist, I can't find it. Does anyone know how to do it best?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace TCPListener
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {        
      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }
    
      TcpListener Listener = null;
      Int32 port = 8080;
      IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");        

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          Listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

          byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[10025];

          while (true)
          {
              int requestCount = 0;
              Listener.Start();
              MessageBox.Show(" >> Listener Started");
              using (var tcpClient = Listener.AcceptTcpClient())
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(" >> Accepted connection from client");

                  using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                  {
                      while (true)
                      {
                          try
                          {
                              requestCount = requestCount++;
                              var bytesRead = networkStream.Read(receiveBuffer, 0, (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                              if (bytesRead == 0)
                              {
                                  // Read returns 0 if the client closes the connection
                                  break;
                              }

                              string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

                              XmlDocument xm = new XmlDocument();
                              xm.LoadXml(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", dataFromClient));
                              XmlElement root = xm.DocumentElement;
                              string rootName = root.FirstChild.Name;                                
                              textBox1.Text = (rootName, dataFromClient);
                          }
                          catch (Exception ex)
                          {
                              MessageBox.Show("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
                              break;
                          }                            
                      }
                  }
                  MessageBox.Show(" >> stopped read loop");
              }
              Listener.Stop();
           }
        }        
     }
 }
```

Comment: When client/server(listener) is on same machine do following 1) Make Listener IP.Any (not loop back 127.0.0.1 which can give errors).  Make client use the IP address of the machine or Machine Name.  If you use DNS GetHost than make sure you use address[1] since address[0] is an IPV6 address and address[1] is an IPV4.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, understand, do you have an example?

Comment: See msdn examples.  The exampls use sockets but you can use any class that inherits  socket like TCP Listener.  Use IPAddress.Any instead of IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1") on listener : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to build something that works.